# angular material table select/deselect row on click

Tags: angular

I have the following table.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m6xfsc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

After clicking on the delete icon, Everything works fine except when I click on the already selected row it does not `de-select`. I want to `de-select` the row if I click on the delete icon again.

I have done the following so far:

> TS

```
  highlight(row) {
      this.highlightedRows.push(row);
  }
```

> HTML

```
    <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
            <button mat-icon-button (click)="onChange()"><mat-icon [ngClass]="{disable:disableChange == true}">launch</mat-icon></button>
            <button mat-icon-button color="warn" (click)="highlight(row)"><mat-icon>delete_outline</mat-icon></button>
        </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="highlight(row)"
        [style.background]="highlightedRows.indexOf(row) != -1 ? 'lightblue' : ''"></mat-row>
```

Comment: It looks like there is a problem with the click as well, when I click on the delete icon, a click for the overall row also registers, but that is outside the scope of the question

Comment: @Mannaroth, it works on clicking the delete icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're appending a row to an array to highlight it so to de-highlight you just remove it. Check for the existence of the clicked row in the highlight array, if its already in the list, remove it, if its not, append it.

```
  highlight(row) {
    if (this.highlightedRows.indexOf(row) > -1) {
      this.highlightedRows.splice(this.highlightedRows.indexOf(row), 1);
    } else {
      this.highlightedRows.push(row);
    }
  }
```

You could also use a highlight object instead of an array:

```
export class AppComponent {
 ...
 highlightedRows = {};
 ...
```

you could then use a unique row value (id, name) to hold the toggle state of each row, on click you simply set the value to its opposite state: `value = !value`, in this case row.name seems to be a fair key name:

```
 <mat-row 
*matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"
(click)="highlightedRows[row.name] = !highlightedRows[row.name]"
[style.background]="highlightedRows[row.name] ? 'lightblue' : ''">
</mat-row>
```

Comment: Odd, still works for me, maybe check the stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u9v7tc